# Already updated compileSdkVersion to 28 after migrating to AndroidX, but still getting gradle error about fontVariationSettings and ttcIndex

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

Migrating to AndroidX includes new attributes fontVariationSettings and ttcIndex. I've tried migrating a project (a Flutter plugin), but get the error below when doing the gradle build. Many users have had the same gradle error as me, but unlike them, I've already

- upgraded my compileSdkVersion to 28 in my build.gradle
- added android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties
- reset the gradle cache through Android Studio (Invalidate Caches/Restart)

My console output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  /Users/davidmccoy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.0.0-beta01.aar/f004b9e22a129b2d333d02089203fb0d/res/values/values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/davidmccoy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.0.0-beta01.aar/f004b9e22a129b2d333d02089203fb0d/res/values/values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had another Android project that I had included in my Flutter application that had not yet been upgraded to AndroidX. So I upgraded that project, and the problem was solved.